# creating a post between two previously adding posts - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a web application and I have a technical problem, if anyone can help.

My app has a Post Model. I want the user to be able add a post between two previously added posts.

For example: In the view there will be: the following posts:

```
"this is the first post"
"this is the second post"
"this is the third post"
"this is the fourth post"
```

I want the user to be able to add a post between the first and the second post so the view will be:

```
"this is the first post"
"This is the last added post"
"this is the second post"
"this is the third post"
"this is the fourth post"
```

Anyone has an idea of how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear and without code samples and further explanation of what you're looking for, it's hard to provide support.  My best guess is that you're sorting posts based on a `created_at` date field.  Instead, you would need to add a new database column to your `post` table that allows a user to enter a custom order.  So you could have "post1 - order: 1", "post2 - order: 2", "post3 - order: 4", "post4 - order: 3" then sort on the `order` column instead of `created_at`

Comment: https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list

Comment: It's my first question here! Sorry for that! Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the [acts_as_list](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) gem.

If you want, you can also use `position` column, and update all positions while adding new one.